# LSTM Loss is 0?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, lstm

I am new to neural nets and I don't know where I am doing it wrong.

My dataset has sensor readings and based on those readings model has to classify (total 4 classes).

| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | .... | col_6 | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| first_1 | first_2 | first_3 | .... | first_6 |  |
| second_1 | second_2 | second_3 | .... | second_6 |  |
| third_1 | third_2 | third_3 | .... | third_6 |  |
| fourth_1 | fourth_2 | fourth_3 | .... | fourth_6 | 0 |

So four rows in x correspond to one y. It is a many to one relationship.

Basically, these are the dimensions of my dataset.

```python
print("Training Shape", X_train_tensors.shape, y_train_tensors.shape)
print("Testing Shape", X_test_tensors.shape, y_test_tensors.shape)
```

The output is

```
Training Shape torch.Size([224735, 4, 6]) torch.Size([224735, 1])
Testing Shape torch.Size([110691, 4, 6]) torch.Size([110691, 1])
```

The LSTM which I have built is

```python
HIDDEN_SIZE = 1
NUM_LAYERS = 2
EPOCHS = 10

class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(RNN, self).__init__()

        self.rnn = nn.LSTM(
            input_size=6,
            hidden_size=HIDDEN_SIZE,
            num_layers=NUM_LAYERS,
            batch_first=True,
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        out, (h_n, h_c) = self.rnn(x, None)
        return out[:, -1, :]  # Return output at last time-step

rnn = RNN()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(rnn.parameters(), lr=0.01)
loss_func = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

for j in range(EPOCHS):
    for i, item in enumerate(X_train_tensors):
        item = item.unsqueeze(0)
        output = rnn(item)
        loss = loss_func(output, y_train_tensors[i])
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    print(f"Epoch: {j}, Loss: {np.average(loss.detach())}")
```

```
Epoch: 0, Loss: 0.0
Epoch: 1, Loss: 0.0
Epoch: 2, Loss: 0.0
Epoch: 3, Loss: 0.0
Epoch: 4, Loss: 0.0
Epoch: 5, Loss: 0.0
Epoch: 6, Loss: 0.0
Epoch: 7, Loss: 0.0
Epoch: 8, Loss: 0.0
Epoch: 9, Loss: 0.0
```

Can someone tell me why I am getting loss as 0?

Answer (score 0):

Your cross-entropy loss is 0, which means the output of the model is in one-hot encoded format. You should add a linear layer at the end of the model and map it through softmax. Also, you need to make sure your training set labels are in one-hot encoded data format.

You should first check whether the output format meets the requirements by the following code:

```py
print(output, y_train_tensors[i])
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the part where you mentioned the "your training set labels are in one-hot encoded data format". I have sensor readings, these are not categorical data.

Comment: Can you execute the output statement mentioned in the answer and post the result?